# Finding Unique text in html file

Tags: python

I am looking to find a way to identify and print sentences in one html file that are different from sentences in another html file. To do this, I have made three functions, one to open, read, strip blank space, and strip the text in the html, one to make a list of original strings that will be compared to, and one to compare the strings to all original strings. This is what I have so far.

```
def openTXT(txt):
    text=open(txt).read()
    StripText=text.strip()
    StripSplitText=StripText.split('.')
    return StripSplitText


def originalSentances(folder):
    sentanceList=[]
    for item in folder:
        for sentance in item:
            if item not in sentanceList:
                sentanceList.append(item)
    return sentanceList

def findUniqueText(massMailerText,inputFolder, outputFile):
    for item in inputFolder:
        results=open('outputFile','w')
        results.write(item)
        text=openTXT(item)
        for sentance in text:
            if sentance in massMailerText:
                pass
            else:
                outputFile.write(sentance)

massMailSentances= originalSentances('original')
findUniqueText(massMailSentances,'modified','uniqueResults.txt')
```

When I run this on a file I get an error that says "No suck file or directory: 'm') Any ideas why this is happening and how I could fix this problem?

If this is helpful, the kernel also prints out this

> IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\Users\amcclure\Desktop\findUniqueText.py in ()
>        28 
>        29 massMailSentances= originalSentances('original')
>   ---> 30 findUniqueText(massMailSentances,'modified','uniqueResults.txt')
>
> C:\Users\amcclure\Desktop\findUniqueText.py in
>   findUniqueText(massMailerText, inputFolder, outputFile)
>        20         results=open('outputFile','w')
>        21         results.write(item)
>   ---> 22         text=openTXT(item)
>        23         for sentance in text:
>        24             if sentance in massMailerText:
>
> C:\Users\amcclure\Desktop\findUniqueText.py in openTXT(txt)
>         2 
>         3 def openTXT(txt):
>   ----> 4     text=open(txt).read()
>         5     StripText=text.strip()
>         6     StripSplitText=StripText.split('.')

Comment: You are assuming that the code will automatically look through the directory `modified`. What it is actually doing, is splitting the word `modified` so `item` is `m`, next it will be `o` then `d` and so on. Look up `os.walk()`

Comment: originalSentances() method does not make sense, because it's receiving a string, not a folder. Thus, each item is a character and I can't imagine what sentance could contain. I doubt that a character could be an iterable in Python